# Concat string Series when some values are empty strings

Tags: python, pandas

How can I vectorize the concatenation of strings in two columns when there are empty strings present? Here is the problem:

My columns in DF:

```
col1 = pd.Series(['text1','','text3'])
col2 = pd.Series(['text1','text2','text3'])
```

When I do:

```
new_col = col1.str.cat(col2, sep='/')
```

it gives:

```
new_col = pd.Series(['text1/text1','','text3/text3'])
```

but it should give:

```
new_col = pd.Series(['text1/text1','/text2','text3/text3'])
```

How can I do this?
Pandas version 0.24.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is missing value instead empty string is necessary parameter `na_rep` in [`Series.str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
col1 = pd.Series(['text1',np.nan,'text3'])
col2 = pd.Series(['text1','text2','text3'])
```

[image]

because if empty string it working nice:

```
col1 = pd.Series(['text1','','text3'])
col2 = pd.Series(['text1','text2','text3'])

new_col = col1.str.cat(col2, sep='/')
print (new_col)
0    text1/text1
1         /text2
2    text3/text3
dtype: object
```

Also is possible use alternative:

```
new_col = col1 + '/' + col2
print (new_col)
0    text1/text1
1         /text2
2    text3/text3
dtype: object
```

Comment: I understand, but in this case, there are empty strings. Is there a nice way of doing it without having to convert all empty strings to np.NaNs?

Comment: @Kaisar - What is your pandas version? In `pandas 0.24.2` it working nice, in last paragraph of answer.

Comment: @Kaisar - It is weird, for me it working nice with empty string. Tested in python 3.6 under win7. How working if use `col1 + '/' + col2` ?

Comment: I replaced to np.NaNs and then did as you said. Thanks!